# JS getting key from values

Tags: javascript

So, I hvae following object in js:

```
var values= {
  'first'       : '42',
  'last'        : '43',
};
```

How do I get the key from the value?

For example, I have `42` and would like to get `first` as the result.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method

```
Object.keys(values).filter(function(key) {return values[key] === '42'})[0];
```

Comment: Thank you. So, I have this : `var cuc_k = Object.keys(values);`. I read the info on the link you sent me. Do you know how I can choose a specific key? For example, the key for value of "42"

Comment: i've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop will help you:

```js
var values= {
  first: '42',
  last: '43',
};

var val = '42', key;

for (key in values) {
  if (values[key] == val) break;
}

document.write(key);
```